# EViews: How to estimate by OLS a more complex regression model?

Tags: eviews

For example I estimated by OLS the following model:

[image]

using an Eviews program file with code:

`equation e1.ls log(cons) c log(sw) log(nsw) log(inc)`

However, I have to now estimate this model:

[image]

But I am not sure how to go about writing the code. I tried typing:

`equation e1.ls log(costs|kwh,pl,pk,pf) c log(kwh) log(pl) log(pk) log(pf) (log(kwh))^2`

However, the first and last terms do not work and I'm not sure how to do it. I would appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

EViews allows you to put the regression in equation form, as in

```
equation e1.ls log(costs)= c(1)*log(kwh)+ c(2)*log(pl)+ c(3)*log(pk) + c(4)*log(pf) + c(5)*(log(kwh))^2
```

but `costs|kwh,pl,pk,pf` doesn't mean anything in EViews.